# Equal to Not equal in or clause of where

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What does the query below mean?

```
    SELECT 
        bid
      , chapter_id 
    FROM
        tblchapter c 
      , tblbook b
    WHERE 
      (b.bid = c.bid OR b.bid <> c.bid)
```

Below is the query and the code between lines is what i am looking for. Please help me. It taking more time. how to rewrite this:

```
    SELECT           
            IDENTITY(INT, 1,1) AS rownum,           
            b.bid AS bid,          
            b.book_id AS book_id,       
            Chapter_S200Received_Date=CONVERT(VARCHAR,chap.chapter_s200_recd_dt,105)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,chap.chapter_s200_recd_dt,108),          
            Chapter_S200Due_Date=CONVERT(VARCHAR,chap.chapter_s200_due_dt,105)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,chap.chapter_s200_due_dt,108),             
            DATEDIFF(dd,getdate(),chap.chapter_s200_due_dt)AS jsScheduleprogress,        
            editor_name = (SELECT user_name FROM EMS_DB.dbo.tblUser WHERE user_id=chap.chapter_s200_editor),          
            isnull(b.book_ce_level,chap.ce_level) as ce_level,          
            DATEADD(day, 2, b.book_s600_due_dt) AS book_s600_due_dt          

    FROM           
            tblBook AS b LEFT OUTER JOIN tblBookStatusUpload AS pp 
            ON b.bid=pp.bid LEFT OUTER JOIN tblLocation AS Loc 
            ON b.book_location=loc.location_id  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblSegregatingCellName AS cel
            ON cel.cell_id=b.book_proof_cell_id LEFT OUTER JOIN 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            (SELECT           
            c.bid,          
            MAX(c.chapter_s200_recd_dt) AS chapter_s200_recd_dt ,          
            MIN(c.chapter_s200_due_dt) AS chapter_s200_due_dt,          
            (SELECT MAX (ce_level) FROM tblchapter c) AS ce_level,          
            (SELECT TOP 1 chapter_s200_editor FROM tblchapter where chapter_s200_editor is not null AND bid=c.bid) AS chapter_s200_editor   

            FROM           
            tblbook AS b INNER JOIN tblchapter AS c 
            ON b.bid=c.bid  INNER JOIN tblChapterStatusDetails AS s     
            ON (c.bid=s.bid or c.bid<>s.bid)   
            WHERE           

            c.chapter_s200_recd_dt >='2011-04-01' AND          
            c.chapter_s200_recd_dt is not null AND            
            c.chapter_s200_due_dt is not null AND           
            c.chapter_s200_finish_dt is  null          
            and  
            s.process_out_dt IS NULL)  

            group by          
            c.bid) AS chap 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
            ON    chap.bid=b.bid          
            where           
            b.bid=chap.bid AND             
            b.book_id is not null  order by b.bid
```

Is there any one to help me.

Comment: How to rewrite the below query since the query is slow  SELECT           
        c.bid,          
        MAX(c.chapter_s200_recd_dt) AS chapter_s200_recd_dt ,          
        MIN(c.chapter_s200_due_dt) AS chapter_s200_due_dt  
                   
        FROM           
        tblbook AS b INNER JOIN tblchapter AS c 
        ON b.bid=c.bid INNER JOIN tblChapterStatusDetails AS s     
        ON (c.bid=s.bid or c.bid<>s.bid)   
        
        group by 
        b.bid

Comment: Do you have the definition of the tables? Looks wrong to me. Looks like its almost a cross join that will get all StatusDetail rows for every Chapter row.

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question to add more code. Code in the comments is *unreadable*. (And pay attention to what aduguid did in their edit to make the existing code readable in your question)

Comment: `b.bid = c.bid OR b.bid <> c.bid` Is this really necessary? There seems to be something wrong as a cross join is being performed her instead of the desired inner join.

Comment: We can *guess* at the intent, but at this point, you're dealing with someone who hasn't caught up with the fact that comma-joins have been unnecessary (and often deprecated) in any mainstream SQL system for *decades*. What were they thinking? Who knows?

Answer (score 0):

The clause `ON (c.bid=s.bid or c.bid<>s.bid)` combined with `and s.process_out_dt IS NULL)` lower down will mean that for every chapter, you will get every status value (not just the status for the chapter/book you are looking at) where the process_out_dt is null and the c.bid is not null.

The s.process_out_dt being not null is explicitly defined in the second clause, while c.bid being null would fail both the = and <> test so would also be excluded.

So this is clearly wrong. There is no value in trying to work out what its trying to do, its just wrong, as everyone who has looked at it can see it just makes no sense.

Have a look at the foreign keys between tblChapterStatusDetail and tblChapter as it is unlikely to be just on bid (Book_id?). There is most probably either a separate chapter_id column, or a combined key of book_id,chapter_id. Hard to know without the table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Above query basically will perform a Cross Join, the output of your query will return all the rows from both tables where bid is not null.

Number of rows returned in your output would be:

> count(b.bid) * count(c.bid)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    bid
  , chapter_id 
FROM
    tblchapter c 
  CROSS JOIN tblbook b
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is incomplete. However, you can give this code a run and check if this is what you want.

```
SELECT c.bid
    ,MAX(c.chapter_s200_recd_dt) AS chapter_s200_recd_dt
    ,MIN(c.chapter_s200_due_dt) AS chapter_s200_due_dt
FROM tblbook AS b 
INNER JOIN tblchapter AS c ON b.bid = c.bid
INNER JOIN tblChapterStatusDetails AS s ON c.bid = s.bid
GROUP BY b.bid
```